# Where is Firebug Post Tab?

Tags: firebug

I've heard that Firebug has Post Tab where the post data could be seen.

However, I don't see such Tab :(

I use Firebug version 1.5.4.

Please help to find the missing Tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is here:

[image]

Also see:

[Debugging Ajax Requests](http://sarfraznawaz.wordpress.com/2009/09/11/debugging-ajax-requests/)